# Strange behaviour in mapValues when returning an option

Tags: scala

I have defined the object below. But I don't understand why the mapValues body only executes in test1. ie. why is the output:

> Calling test1
>
> Calling test2
>
> Mapping: One
>
> Mapping: Two
>
> Mapped: Map(1 -> Xx, 2 -> Xx)

I have tested it with both scala 2.10 and 2.11 with the same results.

```
object Test {

    def test1: Option[String] = {

        val map = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two")
        val mapped = map.mapValues { v =>
            println("Mapping: " + v)
            "Xx"
        }
        None
    }

    def test2: Option[String] = {

        val map = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two")
        val mapped = map.mapValues { v =>
            println("Mapping: " + v)
            "Xx"
        }
        println("Mapped: " + mapped)
        None
    }



    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        println("Calling test1")
        test1
        println("Calling test2")
        test2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer explains the problem, but as a solution, if you want a strict map, just use normal `map`:

```
val m = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two")
val mapped = m.map { 
  case (k,v) => k -> {
    println("Mapping: " + v)
    "Xx"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define your own extension method to do what you want:

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
implicit class HasMapVals[T, U, Repr](val self: GenTraversableLike[(T, U), Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def mapVals[R, That](f: U => R)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (T, R), That]) = {
    self.map { case (k,v) => k -> f(v) }
  }
}

val m = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two")
val mapped = m.mapVals { v =>
  println("Mapping: " + v)
  "Xx"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mapValues` actually returns a [view](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html), so the results are computed lazily. From the scaladoc for `mapValues`:

> **return** a map view which maps every key of this map to f(this(key)). The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.

So for example:

```
val mapped = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two").mapValues { v =>
    println("Mapping: " + v)
    "Xx"
}
```

On it's own this will print nothing when declared. But as soon as `mapped` is accessed, the values will be computed, and the statements will be printed. (In fact, the values will be re-computed *every* time you access `mapped`)

In `Test.test1`, there is nothing accessing `mapped`, so the values are never computed.

In `Test.test2`, you're printing out `mapped`, which triggers the computation of the values.

Comment: And say I want to force the mapValues. What would be the recommended way?

Comment: @user79074 You can chain `.view.force` after `mapValues` to force the evaluation. Or use a strict map as @dhg is suggesting.